# Set 0 at Decimal place if no value found

Tags: c#, logic

I need to set “0” at the end of the decimal place dynamically if less integer number found after decimal place.

Suppose we have value: “535.8”
Now I need to set it as “535.800”
I have following code:

```
string cost = "535.8";
string decplace = "3";

decimal price = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(cost), Convert.ToInt32(decplace));
Console.WriteLine(price);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Unable to get 535.800.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here is your ASAP reply: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: And my -1 (for lack of research) was your other ASAP

Answer (score 1):

You can convert price to string and show upto 3 decimal places with 0's at end.

```
            string cost = "535.8";
            string decplace = "3";

            decimal price = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(cost), Convert.ToInt32(decplace));
            //string.Format("{0:N2}", price);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N3}", price));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price.ToString("N3")
```

[Standard Numeric Format Strings: The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString)

So if the number of decimal should be dynamic:

```
int numDecimalPlaces = 3;
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("N" + numDecimalPlaces));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Format()` to make it possible:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N3}", d));
```

So in your code:

```
string cost = "535.8";
string decplace = "3";

decimal price = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(cost), Convert.ToInt32(decplace));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N" + decplace + "}", price);
Console.ReadLine();
```